# Destroy Navigation bar and tab bar on specific view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have one app to play video that build with swift. I play video on view AVPlayerViewController by story board. and inside the **AVPlayViewController** are contain with **tab bar and navigation bar** that I use on previous screen. during play the Video, when I push the done on the top left it will return to the first before navigation bar. and **I want to remove the navigation bar and tab bar also from my AVPLayerViewController**. *is it possible to remove its?* and **during play the video, when push done, it will return to previous screen that I want**, not go to first screen of app. Everyone, have any idea with this?. 
Thank you.

Comment: you can use `hidden` property to hide `navigation bar` and `tab bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide Navigation And Tab bar in PlayViewController `viewDidLoad` method.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = true
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = true
}
```

Show it in `viewWillDisappear` method:

```
func viewWillDisappear(){
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = false
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: it worked, thank alot, but when I tap on done it don't back to previous page. it thought to the main page. I think it break all my view that I use navigation bar.. have any idea ?... with this @Mr.Bista Thank again.

Comment: AFAIK, It should not break anything.

Comment: Yes, sorry for late to tick the correct answer.. thank for help